# How to calculate refractive index from absorbance, transmittance or reflectance spectra?

Tags: optics, refraction

I have absorbance (Abs), reflectance (R%) and transmittance (T%) data of TiO2
deposited tin film on FTO glass substrate. The data was collected using UV-Vis spectrophotometer.

How to calculate refractive index n
from this?

from the refractive index I will estimate the film thickness, then I will estimate the band gap of the thin film.

I tried with n = (1 + R^1/2) / (1 - R^1/2) where R is reflectance, and with Sweaneopeol method , but it shows large deviation from reported value.

I find another method which given by
n=1/Ts + (1/Ts-1)^1/2  , where n is refractive index and Ts is % transmission coefficient.
**But how can I obtain the transmission coefficient?**

Thank you

Comment: Seems like you dont have enough information. Do you at least know the thickness and optical properties of the substrate? The substrate will play a role in the reflectance.

Comment: yes, I don't have enough information for now, unfortunately.. at least I know the thickness of substrates. until now I saw anothor method to determine the refractive index using the transmittance coefficient but how then I can determine it..? please check my editted post. if you know, please suggest how to proceed.